Is there any way to set clang 15 to compile c++17 by defaul?
Currently I compile my code using the following command. g++ helloWorld.cpp, however this defaults to I believe c++98(MacOs commandlinetools). I want it to compile in c++17/20. I know you can use the command g++ -std=c++17 helloWorld.cpp, which then forces it to compile in c++17. However is there any way to change this behavior so that it is default? When I run the command clang --version i get
clang version 16.0.6
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin


clang 16 I know defaults to c++ 17, which will work for me, but when i run the command g++ --version i get the following. is there any way to change that?
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

this is the clang installed with apples commandlinetools, and the clang I have when I run clang --version, was installed using macports. Any help would be appreciated.
checking my clang version using the following command clang --version,

You have two choices: avoid call g++ on mac, or put shell script which do g++ -std=c++17 "$*" in $PATH.

@user-id-14900042 Could you add that as a answer? I'm not sure what your referring to when you say $PATH

It's the wrong question.  Use a build tool instead and tell it how you want to compile your code.  Make, for example, uses the CXX  and CXXFLAGS variables for that.

Compilers in general need a bunch of flags to behave well (enabling warnings, disabling non-standard extensions, etc). Start using a build system so you don't have to type the flags every time.

It depends what you are trying to do. If you have one fairly sizeable program that you are going to be working on for weeks/months then you should create a Makefile or similar for optimised building with all your options, then you'll compile/build by typing make. If you are learning programming and are compiling example1.cpp then chapter4.cpp, you probably want to define an alias or function in your login profile.

@MarkSetchell, a couple of people have been referring to defining an alias in my login profile. I'm still somewhat new to compiling code in macos so I am unfamilar with what both define a alias means as well as what/where my login profile would be in.

If you type alias ll='ls -l' into your Terminal, and then type ll you'll see how they work. Then maybe try alias compile='g++ -std=c++17 and try your new command compile SomeProgram.cpp

@MarkSetchell, I so should I try something like alias g++='pathtog++'?

No. My suggestion would be that you try what I suggested. I intentionally didn’t name my alias g++ because that would mask (i.e. hide) the existing command and I intentionally included the option for C++17. But I mean, do as you wish.

@MarkSetchell yep i just did alias run='g++ std=c++17', and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks!

@MarkSetchell yep i just did alias run='g++ std=c++17', and it seems to work perfectly. Thanks!

You have a few choices.

avoid call g++ on mac and use explicit path,
overwrite its definition by alias g++=/path/to/clang++16, or
put shell script which wraps around g++

In last choice, write following snippet:
#!/bin/bash
g++ -std=c++17 "$*"

and place it under desired path (I name /path/to/wrap.bash for description purpose) which will be reachable from $PATH environment variable by following these steps:

See how $PATH was set:
echo "$PATH"


Append /path/to to $PATH in your shell's setup script (~/.zshrc or ~/.bash_profile for locally; system-wide configuration is placed on different place):
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to"




I just tried that and I am getting the following error when i run g++ --version: zsh: permission denied: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin. Please help now g++ won't complile at all anymore. I'm afraid I may have just bricked my g++.

@KevinAlvarez It sounds like you don't have permission to execute the compiler in that directory.  That's really a different question. You were given 3 options.  Which one did you try?  Nothing was bricked.  If you used the alias you can unalias it and update your script.

@AllanWind Yep your right, I just managed to fix it by returning it to its default behavior.
